# identify tool found in a car

Tags: tools, tool-identification

I recently bought a second-hand vehicule (Nissan x-trail 2007), and I found under the passenger seat the following tool,

[image]

Initially the "jaws" were not linked, but they slided, and now they won't mave anymore. The handle does not turn. I'm not even sure this is car-related, apologize if it isn't.

> What is this tool?

Comment: That's an antique, get keys made for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, it is pedal lock, for which I don't have the keys (there is a small key hole on the handle), here is a similar lock in position :

[image]

Comment: Nice find! Well, glad you found what it is, lol. Too bad it doesn't appear it will be useful to you. Don't forget to come back and select this as "the answer".